# Ghost dom element navbar fixed top does not stay in position

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3, I have a full screen carousel with a navbar right after. The navbar gets fixed to the top after the user scrolls completely past the carousel. This works fine.

But now when the user BARELY scrolls down and then scrolls up the navbar does not go back to its original place, it stays fixed to the top.

Here is my js for this:

```js
$(function() {
  var lastfixed = undefined,
    spacerEl = undefined,
    fixed = false,
    ghostElHeight = 0;

  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    console.log('scroll top : ' + $(window).scrollTop());

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(".carousel").outerHeight()) {
      fixed = true;
      if (fixed === lastfixed) return
      $(".navbar").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
      ghostElHeight = $(".navbar").outerHeight()
      if (!!!spacerEl) {
        spacerEl = $(".navbar").after(
          '<div class="navspacer" style="height:' + ghostElHeight + 'px">&nbsp;</div>').next();
      }
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() < $(".carousel").height() + ghostElHeight) {
      fixed = false;
      if (fixed === lastfixed) return
      ghostElHeight = 0;
      $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
      !!spacerEl && spacerEl.remove();
      spacerEl = undefined;
    }

    lastfixed = fixed;

  });
});
```

I have also created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thqx9g9b/2/ in order to reproduce the bug you may have to CLICK your scroll wheel, scroll DOWN a tiny bit after the navbar gets fixed to the top, and then scroll UP.

The weird thing is I am doing the SAME thing but with a full screen jumbotron and the bug does not appear.

**UPDATE:** If I add "padding:55px" on the .carousel class, the issue disappears. But this would cause a big border if I am using an image in the carousel.

Here is the updated fiddle with the padding: http://jsfiddle.net/thqx9g9b/3/

*The reason this works on my version with the jumbotron is because the image is set on the parent div and there is no border caused by the padding, I have tried to place padding on various elements inside the carousel but for it to work it needs to be on the parent div, does anyone have some sort of work around for this or am I missing something?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your algorithm seems to be a bit off at the moment.

Now, if you scroll only a bit lower than $(".carousel").outerHeight()

-> fixed does not get true, so the navbar never loses the `navbar-fixed-top` class.

You have to change this

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() < $(".carousel").height() + ghostElHeight) {
```

to

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() < $(".carousel").height()) {
```

then it works as expected. of course you dont have to mess with `ghostElHeight` then. Just add the navspacer in HTML and toggle it with show/hide.

And for another problem:
You introduce a variable `lastfixed`, which makes the code complicated.
better way without `lastfixed`:

change your algo from

```
fixed = true;
if (fixed === lastfixed) return
```

to

```
if (fixed == true) return
fixed = true;
```

and the same for the false-part. this is easier and more clear.

Complete JS code:

```
$(function () {
    var fixed = false;

    $(document).on( 'scroll', function(){

        if($(window).scrollTop()>=$(".carousel").outerHeight())
        {
             if (fixed == true) return
             fixed = true;
             $(".navbar").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
             $(".navspacer").show();
        }

        if($(window).scrollTop()<$(".carousel").height())
        {
             if (fixed == false) return
             fixed = false;
             $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
             $(".navspacer").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

and add navspacer manually after navbar:

```
<div style="height:100px; display: none;" class="navspacer">&nbsp;</div>
```

[DEMO](http://pascha.org/test/10.php)